# How can I browse or download the content of /home in azure functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a time triggered function running on Azure Functions.
This function reads and writes at run time on a **json file in /home/data**.
**How can I retrieve (browse / download) that json file?**
Is my only option to interact with that directory via functions code? Is there some section in the Azure function dashboard where I can retrieve the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get into the console and navigate to the file path using this in your function menu:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using Kudu Console. For that you can navigate to Advance Tools > Go > CMD.

[image]

[image]

You can navigate from the file structure or through console.

[image]

Then you can simply click download button in order to download.

[image]